# Access an element submitName selenium webdriver

Tags: jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium web driver how do i access an input text element that has dynamic id and no name but has attribute of submitName. The document has multiple element and i need to access 4 out of them.

```
<input class="mandy" id="ms__id7" submitName="intYPoliceForce"/>
```

Here's what i have tried so far

Returns nothing

```
   Driver.FindElementByClassName("mandy").GetAttribute("submitName")
```

Doesn't return list of webElements?

```
Driver.FindElement(By.TagName("input"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try smth like this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Css("input[submitName='intYPoliceForce']"));
//if you want to access all items with class mandy
var inputs = driver.FindElements(By.Css(".mandy"));
inputs[0].click() //etc...
//or using xpath analog to access element using beginning of that id
driver.FindElement(By.Css("input[id^='ms__id']"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't manage to access element using submitName directly which i don't understand why submitName attribute cannot be accessed may be it is related to jquery and not javascript?? but can access other attributes.

i went by xpath to access the two input box

```
   /input[@class='mandy' and starts-with(@id, 'ms__id')][1]
/input[@class='mandy' and starts-with(@id, 'ms__id')][2]
```

Comment: This is how I did it.... new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//combobox[@id='intYPoliceForce']//select"))).getFirstSelectedOption()